# How to get divs over an image using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to show an image and divide it using `bootstrap div columns`, but the image is over the `divs`, so I can't `click` or bind `jQuery` to it. Here is my code:

```
#viewer {
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 34px;
}

#left {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: auto;
}

#center {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: auto;
}

#right {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: auto;
}

<div class="container">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="wp-content/themes/Cassia/img/back.jpg" id="viewer">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="left" class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-xs-5">
            </div>

            <div id="center" class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-4">
            </div>

            <div id="right" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-3">
            </div>

        </div>

</div>
```

What am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

To make the image go behind you can add a negative z-index like this:

```css
#viewer {
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 34px;
  z-index: -1;
}
#left {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: auto;
}
#center {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: auto;
}
#right {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://gillespaquette.ca/images/stack-icon.png" id="viewer">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="left" class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-xs-5">Left
    </div>

    <div id="center" class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-4">Center
    </div>

    <div id="right" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-3">Right
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: the image now is not visible, not sure how it's not working in my case , since it's working in your test code!

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little tricky, I did it using JS, maybe there is a simpler solution but anyways, I hope this helps:

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/e12y8u0n/2/)

I added some JS to solve the absolute positioning making parent element have 0 height and thats it.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".row" ).each(function() {
        var newHeight = 0, $this = $( this );
        $.each( $this.children(), function() {
            newHeight += $( this ).height();
        });
        $this.height( newHeight );
    });
    $('.row > div').css('height', '100%');
});
```